# Talend Runtime Background

Tags: java, talend, karaf

I would like to deploy a .jar (build with Talend ESB) in a OSGI contener (Talend Runtime / Karaf ).

I use trun to open a console, start, install etc but when I close the console, my .jar is stopped.

I have seen the karaf documenation to start in background (start idBundle) but this command launch in my console, not in background...

Someone know how to launch my .jar in OSGI in background ?

(PS: Im using Windows)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution : install the container as windows service :

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforESBInstallationandUpgradeGuide54EN/4.2.1%20Talend%20Runtime

Commands are very simples :

1. Browse to the container/bin folder of the Talend Runtime installation directory, then launch the container by executing the trun file as a root user.

> cd /path/to/talend/.../container/bin

2. To install the wrapper feature, simply type:

> trun@root> features:install wrapper

3. To install the service, type in the following command:

> trun@root> wrapper:install

Register the container as a service in automatic start mode, simply type:

> trun@root> wrapper:install -s AUTO_START -n TALEND-CONTAINER -d
>   Talend-Container -D "Talend Container Service"

*where TALEND-CONTAINER is the name of the service, Talend-Container is the display name of the service and "Talend Container Service" is the description of the service.*

**Warning:** don't forget to stop TALEND-CONTAINER service before launch trun.bat in order to install / uninstall bundle.